# Counting elliptic curves by discriminant

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

Enumerating elliptic curves $E/\mathbb{Q}$ sorted by (the absolute value of) their minimal discriminants is a difficult open problem, as is the (likely easier) problem of counting elliptic curves $E/\mathbb{Q}$ given by a minimal Weierstrass model $E_{A,B} : y^2 = x^3 + Ax + B$, ordered by the model discriminant $\Delta(E_{A,B}) = -16(4A^3 + 27B^2)$.

For the question, it is not too hard to show that the number of curves $E$ with $|\Delta(E_{A,B})| \leq X$ is $O(X)$. Counting elliptic curves by their minimal Weierstrass models is essentially equivalent to counting monogenic cubic rings by discriminant, and the number of monic cubic rings of discriminant bounded by $X$ is surely less than the number of cubic rings having discriminant bounded by $X$, and the number of cubic rings having discriminant bounded by $X$ is $O(X)$ by the Davenport-Heilbronn theorem.

I am asking about whether there is any improvement over this bound: is it known that

$$\displaystyle N(X) = \#\{E_{A,B} : 16|4A^3 + 27B^2| \leq X\} = o(X)?$$

Comment: As you probably know, it is conjectured to be asymptotic to an explicit constant times $X^{\frac{5}{6}}$ the following article of Watkins develops some heuristics and surveys others https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/~watkins/papers/heur.pdf.

Comment: @AnweshRay Yes I am aware of that conjecture... I am of course not hoping that this conjecture is solved, but rather asking whether any modest improvement over the 'trivial bound' exists